# How to set directory for Excel.WorkBook.SaveAs()?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have code that converts a .CSV file to a .XLSX file.  The conversion goes well, but the WorkBook.SaveAs(@"file.xslx") method seems to only save the file to C:\Users[MyName]\Documents\file.xlsx.  When I use Excel.Application.GetSaveAsFileName() it defaults to C:\Users[MyName]\Documents with a Save As dialog.

Furthermore, setting Excel.Application.DefaultFilePath doesn't seem to help unless I explicitly state F:.........

I have a relative working directory set, where a.csv is read from:

```
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


        StreamReader a = new StreamReader(@"a.csv");
        var CSVContent = new List<string[]>();
        Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
        excel.DefaultFilePath = @"Output\";   //doesn't do anything
        Excel.Workbook workBook = excel.Workbooks.Add();
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = workBook.ActiveSheet;

        while (!a.EndOfStream)
        {
            string read = a.ReadLine();
            CSVContent.Add(read.Split(','));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < CSVContent.Count; i++)  //write List contents to xlsx Line by Line
        {
            string[] csvLine = CSVContent[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < csvLine.Length; j++)
            {
                sheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = csvLine[j]; //Cells begin at 1 in Excel
            }
        }

        var b = excel.GetSaveAsFilename("a.xlsx");

        workBook.SaveAs(b);
        workBook.Close();
```

How do I get workbook.SaveAs() to save into the solution relative working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on relative paths tends to be problematic. If you want to save it to the current directory of the application, use `Environment.CurrentDirectory`, that is:

```
var b = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\a.xlsx";
```